# AsyncTask in other class error in android java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

hi im trying to use asynctask in other class but when i call it it doesn't work

here is my code

```
package com.examplee.test;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class test extends Activity {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new ProgressTask(test.this).execute();  // THIS IS ERROR CANNOT USE THIS IN STATIC CONTEXT and when i change static thing class doesn't work anymore


        }

        private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
            private ProgressDialog dialog;

            public ProgressTask(test mainActivity) {
                context = mainActivity;
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            }

            private Context context;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait For Some Time...");
                this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
                this.dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
                this.dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                this.dialog.show();
            }

                @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                    if (success) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            }

            protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

                // My Work i have to perform

                return null; 


              }
        }

    }
```

can anybody correct this code ?
even i try changing everything on progresstask.execute ,nothing is working :(

i would appreciate if anybody could take time and help me sort it out :)

this line is what i needed to stay in class to

**public static void main(String[] args)**

Comment: This class doesn't look static to me... How do you start this Activivty?

Comment: you´re trying to run a `main` method in Android. Please, refer to the Android developers documentation

Comment: i changed the topic i mean any class it doesn't able to execute new ProgressTask(test.this).execute();  it can execute in MainActivity without any problem

Comment: @eduyayo public static void main(String[] args) { this is required to run the class i can not change this line main line sorry im not that expert in java just beginner need code help

Comment: yes, @radioactive, I´ve downvoted the question because of that. You cannot run android runtime outside android runtime. You *may* with a unit testing framework but not with a simple `main`

Comment: can you fix this bro ?

Comment: nope, read my comment

Comment: "does not work -- can you fix"? is vague and not what StackOverflow is about...

Comment: @shkschneider  i explained everything in question i want to run the asnyc task from other class if you can modify it better way i would be happy no matters if whole code chnages

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to start the application in android. In `Java`, you will use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

But in `android`, it starts the activity from `onCreate` method.

Look at the `activity` lifecycle :

[image]

So, it should be

```
public class Test extends Activity {

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance)
    {
       // This onCreate method will be called first when activity starts
       super.onCreate(saveInstance);
      new ProgressTask(test.this).execute();
    }

   class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
   {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
     }
    }
   }
```

The above is just a template. You need to change according to your need.

Comment: @radioactive What do you mean? You need run your program either in emulator or real device. This is not like java application to run and get the ouput in console. Go [here](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) and start learn the basic :)